# LibreOffice ignores Ubuntu regional settings

Tags: libreoffice, locale

LibreOffice ignores Ubuntu regional settings

[image]

Although date in Russia should be `DD.MM.YYYY` it displays `MM/DD/YYYY`.

How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LibreOffice has its own locale settings under **<kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>Language Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Languages</kbd>**:

[image: language settings screenshot]

Make sure the correct locale setting is configured here and that your input data matches one of the date acceptance patterns, otherwise it won't be recognized as date by LibreOffice.